# Is the QR Algorithm guaranteed to compute eigenvectors?

Tags: algorithms, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, numerics

I'm writing some C++ matrix library for hobby.
For computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors, I referred the following "Francis double step QR algorithm":

In particular, page 82 of https://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter4.pdf

This is my code:
https://github.com/frozenca/Ndim-Matrix/blob/main/LinalgOps.h#L1045

My implementation correctly computes eigenvalues, but fails to compute eigenvectors, except the first eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue.

For $\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
-9 & 7 & 5 & 5 \\
-5 & 2 & 6 & 6 \\
-7 & 2 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}$, Wolframalpha gives the following result:

$\lambda_{1} = 12.6009, \lambda_{2} = 4.2635, \lambda_{3} = 2.5983, \lambda_{4} = 0.5373$
with corresponding eigenvectors

$v_1 = (0.520545, 0.706921, 0.728858, 1)$

$v_2 = (-2.02909, -7.68532, -0.446183, 1)$

$v_3 = (8.65707, 12.3871, 3.67796, 1) $

$v_4 = (-0.748529, -0.608655, -1.56064, 1)$

My code outputs the following:

```
(12.6009,0) {(0.343092,0), (0.465934,0), (0.480393,0), (0.659103,0)}
Av(normalized) : {(0.343092,0), (0.465934,0), (0.480393,0), (0.659103,0)}
(4.26349,0) {(0.101326,0), (0.836911,0), (-0.197859,0), (-0.500164,0)}
Av(normalized) : {(-0.180481,0), (0.234039,0), (-0.48548,0), (-0.822777,0)}
(2.59833,0) {(0.924778,0), (-0.243128,0), (-0.270181,0), (-0.112592,0)}
Av(normalized) : {(-0.203286,0), (-0.674777,0), (-0.41863,0), (-0.572799,0)}
(0.537284,0) {(0.12964,0), (-0.152886,0), (0.810603,0), (-0.55022,0)}
Av(normalized) : {(-0.276698,0), (-0.77434,0), (0.503774,0), (0.264664,0)}
```

`,0` part is the imaginary part.

I collected the column vectors of the $Q$ matrix upon convergence of the algorithm.

The eigenvalues are correct, and the first eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ is also correct - being equal to the normalized $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}$. But other eigenvectors seem just broken. Really weird that only one eigenvector is correct.

Is the paper wrong? Should I use another algorithm for computing eigenvectors? Or just is my implementation broken?

Answer (score 2):

Self-answer: The QR algorithm itself produces eigenvectors only if the matrix is normal. In general, it only produces the Schur form. To compute eigenvectors we must do backward substitution, knowing that the span of the Schur vectors is equal to the whole eigenspace.

The implementation is done!

https://github.com/frozenca/Ndim-Matrix